# How to make ctrlp search only ~/Documents directory?

Tags: ctrlp

ctrlp searches my home directory.
Is there a line I can put in my vimrc so that ctrlp only searches my ~/Documents directory by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in my vimrc did the trick:

```
" set cwd so Ctrl-P starts searches from Documents when Vim opens
cd /home/user_name/Documents/
```